# Batch Script - Create directory and copy files into that directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, task

I need to make a directory with a time stamp and then copy files into that created directory. I am unsure how to copy files into a directory this created directory.

When I attempt to create the directory with `xcopy`, it asks me to choose `file or directory`; I would like to automate this process for a Task.

Is there a way to "dynamically" insert the destination path or tell it to make it a directory?

Here is what I have so far...

```
@echo off
For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do (
Set DayW=%%A
Set Day=%%B
Set Month=%%C
Set Year=%%D
Set All=%%A-%%B-%%C-%%D
)
For /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:,. " %%A in ('echo %time%') do (
set /a "Hour=100%%A%%100"
set Min=%%B
set Sec=%%C
)
if %Hour% geq 12 (
set AMPM=PM
set /a "Hour-=12"
) else set "AMPM=AM"
if %Hour% equ 0 set "Hour=12"
if %Hour% lss 10 set "Hour=0%Hour%"
set "Allm=%Hour%.%Min%.%Sec%%AMPM%"

echo on

/md "D:\Development\MySQLBatch\CSL20\Divi-child files\Backup- %All%"

xcopy /s /y "D:\Development\CenterServingLeaderv2\wp-content\themes\Divi child" "D:\Development\MySQLBatch\CSL20\Divi-child files\Backup- %All%"
```

This asks if I want a `file or directory` and once I insert `d` it populates the directory correctly. I want to automate this.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: There is a typo: remove the leading `/` from `/md`! The prompt is caused by `xcopy`; I guess as soon as you fix the said typo it should no longer ask for `F` or `D`, but if it still does, simply append a backslash to the destination directory: `"...\Backup- %All%"`

Comment: XCopy has a switch that says it's a directory `/I` *If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.*. Type `xcopy /?` as there are other useful switches such as `/C` *Continues copying even if errors occur.*

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you! That helped.

Comment: @Noodles Your suggestion was also helpful, thank you!